# clarification on HDFS replication

Tags: hdfs, bigdata

If we have a file divided into 128MB blocks and to be stored in HDFS, also lets say we have 2 racks each having 5 nodes to replicate data. 
How the replication happens?
Will the different data blocks (lets say 2,3,4) of a same file can be stored on same node(lets say datanode1) in HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the number of data nodes must be greater than or equal to the replication factor.

How the replication happens: read this article: https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/02/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/

Different data blocks of same file can be stored on same data node - Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Even I felt the same. However I was confused as in a quiz, the right answer was "HDFS will guarantee that no 2 blocks of the same file will be stored in same node". This confused me.